# Deploy Jboss Prod

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring boot and my application server is Jboss.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.7.RELEASE:compile
  org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.7.RELEASE:compile
   org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.10:compile
  org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
    org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
    org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
    antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
    org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
    dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
    org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
  org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
  javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
  org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.7.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.7.RELEASE:compile
    org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.11.RELEASE:compile
  org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.11.RELEASE:compile
```

When I start my application in production I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource

Comment: Can you provide more details? JBoss EAP Version? The likely cause is JBOSS do not support Hibernate 5 yet or conflicts with versions;

Comment: ok, Jboss EAP 6.4 update 10 and Java 8 build 131

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss EAP 6.4 do not support Hibernate 5 yet and also conflicts with JPA version.

Downgrade to Hibernate 4 this you can achieve by adding hibernate.version property in pom.xml

`<properties>
      <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
   </properties>`

Then create a new jboss-deployment-structure.xml file under META-INF directory and copy below content and try

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jpa"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.annotation.api" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

`